# If photons have a wave particle duality would gravitons have a wave particle duality?

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

If electromagnetic waves are the same as photons would gravitational waves be the same as gravitons?

Comment: The electromagnetic waves are **not** the same as photons. The former are solutions of field propagation, the latter is the force carrier thereof, described as basis of the Lie algebra the fields take values in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all particles, atoms, and molecules smaller than about a C60 molecule exhibit both wave and particle properties. It's not until the object is larger than its wave function that it begins to lose its wave nature.

Comment: This answer is wrong in all possible respects as: 1) there is no such thing as *both particle and wave properties*, and even if there were, it would not depend on the size of the particle (assumed one knows how to measure sizes). 2) The object being larger doesn't imply it "loses" the wave nature. The correct answer would be that the general equations describing the dynamics are neither the Newton's laws, nor pure wave equations, rather they are (whatever) field theory equations.